# An R script to find and replace old database names with new ones in SQL queries

Tags: r, replace, gsub

Recently there was an overhaul to the database names I work with. I'd really like to be able to avoid having to fix all of the queries I use by hand with manual find and replace. I'd like to make an R script that will take in a sql file as input and then replace a database name with its updated/new name.

I know that I can use `gsub` to replace parts of strings

i.e.

```
x <- c("12345a", "23456a", "34567a", "45678a", "56789a")
gsub("a","b",x)
"12345b" "23456b" "34567b" "45678b" "56789b"
```

But I'm not trying to replace a single part of a string with a single new entry and I have a feeling that I can't simply create two variables of the database names and then pass gsub on a file. Is gsub the right direction or maybe stringr has some options?

Comment: Regex can be used in cases when you know what pattern the strings you need to match and context these strings appear in. If you can't define the pattern and contexts, it is not possible. Note that SQL is code and regex is bad at handling code. If you know an SQL parser for R that would be the best choice.

Comment: First question, is regex a package for R?

Second question, I'm looking for an exact 1:1 name replace. Find old name, replace new name. Would it be able to handle that?

Comment: "Regex" = [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).  In `gsub("a","b",x)`, `a` is a regex pattern matching `a`. For example, if you want to match `a` only when it is preceded with `INTO` and whitespace, you could use `gsub("\\bINTO\\s+\\Ka","b",x, perl=TRUE)`.

Comment: Well that looks non-intuitive. So is there a reasonable way to accomplish this using an R script?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you could do this in the fewest keystrokes using command line tools like `sed` and `grep`, and technically, there are probably better tools to actually parse the `sql` and make sure you don't have any unintended effects,  but I completely understand your desire to use `R` if you are already very comfortable working in the language and environment.

I find myself doing many tasks that `R` (easy to forget it was just supposed to be a statistical computing language) wasn't ever intended for just because it's flexible/powerful enough 99% of the time and switching languages takes a lot of mental overhead.

One potential way to do it: I'd definitely make sure to have a good backup somewhere before doing any testing, and keep an eye out for unintended substitution.

I also would suggest putting all your column names in a .csv file with an "Old" and a "New" column for creating and editing, much easier to keep up with and make sure your two lists are properly line up in (gasp) Excel if your handling more than 3-4 names replacements.

Example .csv file format:

```
library(data.table)

## Generate example replacements csv file to see the format used
Replacements <- data.table(Old = c("Column_1a","Column_2a","Column_3a"),
                           New = c("Column_1b","Column_2b","Column_3b"))

fwrite(Replacements,"Replacements.csv",)
```

Once you have your .csv, you can create a function to loop through a list of files in your folder with the extension ".sql".

```
library(magrittr)
library(stringi)

## Read in list of replacements
Replacements <- fread("Replacements.csv")

## Use the folder with your queries as "path"
QueryList <- list.files(path = getwd(), pattern = "*.sql$")    

## Create a function to read, transform, and write a copy
sql_replacer <- function(FileName = NULL, oldNames = NULL, newNames = NULL) {
  FileName %>% 
    readLines() %>%
    stri_replace_all_regex(.,"\\b"%s+%oldNames%s+%"\\b",newNames,vectorize_all = FALSE) %>% 
    writeLines(., paste0("New_",FileName))
}

## Apply the "sql_replacer" function to all of your files
## with a list of old names and new ones
lapply(QueryList, sql_replacer, oldNames = Replacements$Old, newNames = Replacements$New)
```

This will read a file "Example.sql"

```
SELECT
Column_1a,
Column_2a,
Column_3a
FROM ExampleDB.ExampleTable
WHERE Column_1a = 2;
```

And save a copy as "New_Example.sql".

```
SELECT
Column_1b,
Column_2b,
Column_3b
FROM ExampleDB.ExampleTable
WHERE Column_1b = 2;
```

Comment: This is great, but is there a way to have this do a 1:1 replacement so that row 1 in column 1 is replaced by row 1 in column 2, row 2 in column 1 replaced by row 2 by column 2?

Comment: If I understand correctly, this method does the 1:1 replacement that you are looking for. For example, if you have a column named "col_xxx" in your query and you had a row in your `Replacements` data.frame with values "col_xxx" and "new_colname" in the `Old` and `New` columns respectively, all occurrences of the full word "col_xxx" would be replaced with "new_colname". This 1:1 replacement is repeated for all pairs of `Old` and `New` represented by a row in the data.frame.